Source code is not getting updated with docker compose for development
I've 3 app in a single repo. For a project it's Api, Admin UI & Front-end. In all of those I'm facing the issue that the source code is not getting updated correctly. Following is the Dockerfile for Api
FROM golang:1.22.5-alpine3.20

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY go.mod go.sum ./
RUN go mod download && go mod verify

COPY . .
RUN go build -v -o /usr/local/bin/app ./

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["app"]

Following is docker-compose.yaml
services:
  db:
    image: mariadb:10.5.25
    restart: always
    # ...
  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    # ...
  API: # Our focus is in here
    container_name: bjm_api
    build: ./api
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    develop:
      watch:
        - action: sync
          path: ./api
          target: /usr/src/app
    networks:
      - bjm_net
    volumes:
      - api_data_bjm:/app/logs
    env_file: ./api/.env
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
  admin:
    container_name: bjm_admin
    build: ./admin
    ports:
      - "3001:3001"
    # ...
    depends_on:
      api:
        condition: service_started
  web:
    container_name: bjm_web
    build: ./web
    ports:
      - "3002:3002"
    # ...
    depends_on:
      api:
        condition: service_started

networks:
  bjm_net:
    name: bjm-net
volumes:
  db_data_bjm:
    driver: local
  api_data_bjm:
    driver: local


Then ran with docker compose up --watch
Steps to reproduce the issue

After the above do change something in the (go file) code
Notice that the thing is not updated in the output.
But in terminal it shows that updated code is taken into container. Following is shown in terminal

bjm_api    | ➡ POST /v1/auth/sign-in - 400
           ⦿ Syncing "api" after changes were detected
           ⦿ Syncing "api" after changes were detected

I think the code was syncked but the executable is not being built. How to solve this?
My setup
Docker version 27.1.1
Ubuntu 24.04

Go is a compiled language.  Just mapping the original Go source code into the container doesn't do anything, because it doesn't get run.  Instead, your Dockerfile produces the compiled app binary, and that's what gets run.  When your source code changes, you need to rebuild the image (and with it the Go binary).
The Compose watch block has a couple of different action values.  You've set it to sync, which tries to copy files into the container.  You actually need to set it to rebuild to get your Go application rebuilt.
version: '4.x'  # develop: not in Compose file formats 2.x/3.x
services:
  api:
    build: ./api
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    develop:
      watch:
        - action: rebuild  # <--- change this
          path: ./api
    volumes:
      - api_data_bjm:/app/logs
    env_file: ./api/.env
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy


Thank you :) You're correct. there is no need to sync since we need to rebuild the container. But the way this works I don't like it. after copying files to the container, I just need to re-build the binary. instead, now it's rebuilding the whole Image and restarting all other services associated with it & this takes time. So every time I change something this'll take 3-10 seconds :(. I think development in this setup is not worth it.
Do you've any suggestions for improving the situation? My goal was using docker for ONLY development

I'd use your host OS's package manager to install the Go toolchain.  You shouldn't need an isolated environment to do basic development.

Legit. The issue is other complicated things are also involved in the project & the Go project is only part of the whole project. This is why I decided to use docker.

@David Maze's answer is a good solution when not using air
It turned out on further inspection that I was not using auto-reload (configured with air), but instead using standard way to build & run the binary. this is not efficient for development purposes. Now I'm using air to pick up code changes & automatically build the binary & serve that, No need to image rebuild which also triggers rebuild on dependant containers.
Following is my Dockerfile
FROM golang:1.22.5-alpine3.20

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# install air
RUN go install github.com/air-verse/air@latest

# pre-copy/cache go.mod for pre-downloading dependencies and only redownloading them
# in subsequent builds if they change
COPY go.mod go.sum ./
RUN go mod download && go mod verify

COPY . .
# RUN go build -v -o /usr/local/bin/app ./ # not necessary for air

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["air"] # run with air

Updated docker-compose.yaml
services:
  api:
    container_name: bjm_api
    build: ./api
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    develop:
      watch:
        - action: sync # get updated file from host so air can rebuild bin
          path: ./api #path on host
          target: /usr/src/app # path on container
          ignore:
            - .idea/
            - storage/
            - README.md
            - Todo.md
            - .gitignore
            - .dockerignore
    # ...
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy

This way API service gets all the updates but other services don't get rebuilt/ restarted. This makes it fast.
